# Is there an NBT tag that makes entities invisIble?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there an NBT tag that can make entities invisible without having to use the potion effect with *ShowParticles:0*? I would make my command writing **A** **LOT** easier

Answer (score 2):

## No.

You have to use the potion effect. The only exception are armour stands: `Invisible:1`